# Matching error: "unknown parameters lpha"

Tags: r

I'm following this slides for propensity score matching in R and getting the error: "unknown parameters lpha"

This is my code:

```
data(lalonde, package = 'Matching')
lalonde.formu <- treat ~ age + educ + black + hisp + married + nodegr + re74 + re75
glm1 <- glm(lalonde.formu, family = binomial, data = lalonde)
library(Matching)
ps <- fitted(glm1) # Propensity scores
Y <- lalonde$re78 # Dependent variable, real earnings in 1978
Tr <- lalonde$treat # Treatment indicator
rr <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=ps, M=1, ties=FALSE)
summary(rr) # The default estimate is ATT here
library(granovaGG)
matches <- data.frame(Treat=lalonde[rr$index.treated, 're78'], Control=lalonde[rr$index.control, 're78'])
print(granovagg.ds(matches))
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[image: error]

Comment: it works for me - maybe try restarting your r session?

Comment: @jeremycg, it works but I get the error at the end. I will upload a screenshot soon

Comment: I don;t get the error, but it looks like an error in the call to ggplot, where the code has lpha instead of alpha see line 370 [here](https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG/blob/9edb172dd2eabb02ff429f62c6dbfc3bdc457ec4/R/granovagg.ds.R)

Comment: Thanks @jeremycg. I will report that bug in github

Comment: I've already made a [pull request](https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG/pull/160) :)

Comment: Thanks for finding this error!